# What is high-level software QA?

Tags: terminology

I've read the following in a job advertisement:

> Experience with high level software QA [...]

What is it or what could it be?

Answer (score 14):

Welcome to SQA, user5440.  "High level software QA" could refer to a architect-level position, or a management position, or something else; maybe even a job testing zeppelin software, or testing marijuana distribution software in California.  Or it might mean ordinary testing from the perspective of someone who doesn't know anything about software, or who wants to make the job sound more exciting than it really is.

We get a lot of "what does this phrase in this job advertisement mean?" kind of questions here. You aren't going to find a good answer unless you actually ask the company who posted the advertisement.  And there is nothing wrong with dashing off a note to the company asking, "What did you mean by that?"

Comment: "testing marijuana distribution software in California" actually made me laugh out loud

Comment: seconded on the "testing marijuana distribution software in California".